# Force a reload of page in Chrome using Javascript [no cache]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, webkit, browser-cache

I need to reload a page using JavaScript and ensure that it does not pull from the browser cache but instead reloads the page from the server. 
[As elements of the page will have changed in the interim]

On IE and FF I found that the following code worked fine;

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

However it does not work on Chrome or Safari.

I tried the following, but also to no avail;

```
window.location.replace(location.href);
document.location.reload(true);
document.location.replace(location.href);
```

Is there a solution to this issue?

**Findings**

After looking into this I have found that this issue is HTTP Protocol handling;

1. Chrome sends a request with `Pragma: no-cache` HTTP field
2. Server responds with `Last-Modified: DATE1` field
3. JS uses `location.reload(true)` to force a reload from server not cache
4. Chrome sends a request with `If-Modified-Since: DATE1` field
5. Server responds with `HTTP Status 304 Not Modified`

The server application is at fault for not noticing the state change in the dynamic page content, and thus not returning a `200`.
However, Chrome/WebKit is the only browser that sends a `If-Modified-Since` field when the JS `location.reload(true)` is called.

I thought I would put my findings here in-case someone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 20):

You can use this hack:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: window.location.href,
        headers: {
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Expires": -1,
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
        }
    }).done(function () {
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

Comment: Although not tested, but your answer is very wise and it seems that really is the right way! I recommend using "POST" which is sure that the cache will not affect. +1 for you answer! Thanks!

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Though it's worth remember that a.) you'll be using more bandwidth to get the page via ajax and then again once that's done and b.) the client will be sat waiting for the ajax call to complete before they see the page reload.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, however it creates a reload loop. How to avoid that?

Comment: @Mateng what do you mean by a loop?

Comment: The page keeps reloading and never finishes (Firefox).

Comment: You don't need this in Firefox, just use window.location.reload(true);

Comment: It's working fine on both Chrome and Firefox. Thumbs Up!

Comment: This works only for the page, not for the assets that the page loads.

Answer (score 10):

To ensure the page isn't loaded from cache you can add some unique number to query:

```
window.location = location.href + '?upd=' + 123456;
```

You also can use date instead of 123456

Comment: However, when a person then navigates to location.href, using a navigation item say, then it loads the old data from the cache.

Comment: You can set cache policy for those documents, that you don't want to load from cache. You can add such headers to server response:
Cache-Control "max-age=7200, must-revalidate"

Comment: By the way in my chrome (21.0.1145) window.location.reload() works fine.

Comment: OK. The issue has to do with HTTP protocol handshaking.

1. initial Chrome request includes header containing; Pragma: no-cache

2. Server responds with a header containing; Last-Modified: DATE1.

3. JS calls location.reload(true); which should force ignoring the cache

4. Chrome request contains; If-Modified-Since: DATE1.
5: The server responds with; Http status: 304 not modified

Other browsers do not include the If-Modified-Since header field when location.load(true) as it is meant to force a get. 
WebKit browsers do.

Comment: let url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
window.location = url + '?upd=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to ensure my application file is force reloaded on chrome:

```
    var oAjax = new XMLHttpRequest;
    oAjax.open( 'get', '/path/to/my/app.js' );
    oAjax.setRequestHeader( 'Pragma', 'no-cache' );
    oAjax.send();
    oAjax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( oAjax.readyState === 4 ) {
            self.location.reload();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This reloaded the page, but still used cached images in Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Try `window.location = window.location`

Comment: This, but would pre-pend something like a random string with the timestamp in the query string (either by adding "&timestamp=" or "?timestamp=" depending on if their is a "?" in the path already or not).

Answer (score 1):

Great findings! I just encountered the same issue and this really helps a lot!
However, in addition to your finding, it seems that Chrome always sends a GET request for location.reload()...IE/FF is repeating the last request instead.