# location.reload(true) does not work in google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am developing javascript page which will read from file every five minutes. Problem is that whenever the old file is deleted and new file is coming, it is not loaded in google chrome because it will keep reading from the chache

I have tried searching many links but no help

location.reload(true)

The above command works in Microsoft edge and firefox without any problem but does not work in google chrome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719505/force-a-reload-of-page-in-chrome-using-javascript-no-cache

Comment: `location.reload(true)` is that the entire code in your file? What is the code you're using to read your file? , Have you tried meta tags for refreshing?